# vue-cli (webpack) unexpected character

Tags: webpack, vue-cli-4

I have an issue with sass files (when I remove sass files all build process pass successfully), the error is:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently, no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

As I understand I need to add some loader to my `vue.config.js`, but I do not understand what exactly loader I need to add?? From the error, it's not clear which file/line exactly causing the issue (I have several `scss`  files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install sass loader and node-sass

Run `npm install -D sass-loader node-sass`. You can see more [here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html)